# node bignum install fails

Tags: node.js, npm, bignum

I can' find any inforamtions about my bignum install fails, any idea ?

On OSX 10.12

Node 13.3.0

here are the errors, tried bignum@10.12 same problem

python2.7 is in PATH

Thanks

---

````
> prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild

prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=13.3.0 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=darwin)
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bignum/bignum.o
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:202:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:22:1: error: no viable conversion from 'Local<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Isolate *'
X(Boolean)
^~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:18:23: note: expanded from macro 'X'
      val->To ## TYPE(isolate->GetCurrentContext())                            \
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:2762:37: note: passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
  Local<Boolean> ToBoolean(Isolate* isolate) const;
                                    ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:202:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_converters.h:67:
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:40:1: error: no viable conversion from 'Local<v8::Context>' to 'v8::Isolate *'
X(bool, Boolean)
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../nan/nan_converters_43_inl.h:37:29: note: expanded from macro 'X'
  return val->NAME ## Value(isolate->GetCurrentContext());                     \
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:2771:30: note: passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
  bool BooleanValue(Isolate* isolate) const;
                             ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:203:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:103:42: error: no viable conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'Local<v8::Context>'
  return scope.Escape(v8::Function::New( isolate
                                         ^~~~~~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:189:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'const v8::Local<v8::Context> &' for 1st argument
class Local {
      ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:189:7: note: candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from 'v8::Isolate *' to 'v8::Local<v8::Context> &&' for 1st argument
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:193:13: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'Local<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'v8::Isolate *'
  V8_INLINE Local(Local<S> that)
            ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:4313:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'context' here
      Local<Context> context, FunctionCallback callback,
                     ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:203:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:37: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 2, have 1
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~      ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:5688:3: note: 'New' declared here
  static Local<Value> New(Isolate* isolate, Local<String> value);
  ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:203:
In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189:
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:58: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:337:60: error: expected expression
  return v8::StringObject::New(value).As<v8::StringObject>();
                                                           ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
../../nan/nan.h:1034:53: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
      v8::Local<v8::String> string = from->ToString();
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:2750:3: note: 'ToString' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<String> ToString(
  ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
../../nan/nan.h:1044:37: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'v8::Isolate *' with an lvalue of type 'char *'
        length_ = string->WriteUtf8(str_, static_cast<int>(len), 0, flags);
                                    ^~~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:2947:26: note: passing argument to parameter 'isolate' here
  int WriteUtf8(Isolate* isolate, char* buffer, int length = -1,
                         ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
../../nan/nan.h:1818:28: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
    New(persistentHandle)->Set(New(key).ToLocalChecked(), value);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
../../nan/nan.h:1824:28: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
    New(persistentHandle)->Set(key, value);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
../../nan/nan.h:1830:28: error: no matching member function for call to 'Set'
    New(persistentHandle)->Set(index, value);
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3547:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context,
                                    ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3550:37: note: candidate function not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT Maybe<bool> Set(Local<Context> context, uint32_t index,
                                    ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
../../nan/nan.h:1836:32: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
        New(persistentHandle)->Get(New(key).ToLocalChecked()));
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
../../nan/nan.h:1842:48: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    return scope.Escape(New(persistentHandle)->Get(key));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
../../nan/nan.h:1847:48: error: no matching member function for call to 'Get'
    return scope.Escape(New(persistentHandle)->Get(index));
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3594:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:3597:43: note: candidate function not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Value> Get(Local<Context> context,
                                          ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2657:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:24:25: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    assert(persistent().IsNearDeath());
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                        ^
In file included from ../bignum.cc:8:
In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:2657:
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:67:18: error: no member named 'MarkIndependent' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    persistent().MarkIndependent();
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
../../nan/nan_object_wrap.h:124:26: error: no member named 'IsNearDeath' in 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object, v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<v8::Object> >'
    assert(wrap->handle_.IsNearDeath());
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                        ^
../bignum.cc:291:70: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
  target->Set(Nan::New("BigNum").ToLocalChecked(), tmpl->GetFunction());
                                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:6283:3: note: 'GetFunction' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Function> GetFunction(
  ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))
                              ^
../bignum.cc:385:71: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was not specified
        Nan::New<FunctionTemplate>(constructor_template)->GetFunction(), len, newArgs);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8.h:6283:3: note: 'GetFunction' declared here
  V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT MaybeLocal<Function> GetFunction(
  ^
/Users/pimerle/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.3.0/include/node/v8config.h:419:31: note: expanded from macro 'V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT'
#define V8_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT __attribute__((warn_unused_result))```
````

Comment: Can you add more context to your question so people can better answer your question? What else do people need to know to answer your question? More is always better :)

Comment: Try downgrading to node.js 10 LTS.